# Routing Between Intranet and Internet

Tags: internet, vpn, ip, routing, intranet

I have 2 ADSL Modems:

One is for intranet connectivity, the other is for accessing the internet.

I connect the intranet to my PC on network interface "Local Area Connection", and connect to internet using a wireless interface.

When I connect to the intranet with a vpn connection I lose my connectivity to the internet.

I have two ranges of ip address:

1. 10.10.10.x
2. 192.168.1.x

How can I route with two IP address ranges?

My Os :Win Server 2008 R2
Vpn connection  :PPTP

I Want Use Internet And Intranet all togher

Comment: Hello Ehsan, could you please clarify "intranet" here a bit more? What do you want to do? You want to give internet access to the intranet? The more specific you ask, the better a possible answer can be.

Comment: Do you manually configure the intranet connection or are you using DHCP? Either way, make sure no gateway is configured.

Answer (score 0):

VPN connection usually involve specifying some custom routes for your network interface.
Use command **route** (linux ip route) to check if any rules are applied when you are connecting via VPN. They might be the problem or lack of them (the proper ones) might be the problem.

Pity you did not share some details like what is your OS, what kind of software/hardware are you using for VPN (is it OpenVPN or maybe Cisco ASA or something else)...